# Quantitative Analysis Games on Investing?

Tags: education

I have been playing a quantitative investing game (instructions [here](http://www.salserver.tkk.fi/KtPeli/instructions.php)) that is actually quite interesting, teams have some time to decide their next moves. It requires all kind of knowledge such as spreadsheet -programming, residual -analysis, portfolion -management, allocation, XYZ -- variables and in the end the challenge is to develop the politics that maximize the utility in the game (and the utility functions change unexpectedly in the game) -- a real dynamic programming problem at the best. I feel it is quite fun and useful way to practice quantitative skills (besides extremely fast programming during sprints and good preparation drives analysis skills such as R and statistics/over-fitting/etc, besides a lot of fun-hectic time in a group).

1. Can you come up with more `"research labs"` (aka games) like that perhaps more realistic with historical data?
2. They do not need to be like the above, they could be on a more specific segment such as speculation with inverse yield curve with historical-data-approximated values or anything like that, ideas?
3. I am thinking that there may be some sort of competitions in real-life on this kind of issues, are there? Experience?

I find this kind of games/challenges could be quite driving agent to teach and learn different kind of usually-low-profile quantitative issues, very well monopoly works but it is a bit too static to learn quantitative skills to analyze and synthesize information.

*P.s. I am now not looking for mock `investing or financial` games but games where you get a massive amount of data and you have some goal like in the example game, actually the massive amount of data is not essential -- just on some challenging quantitative issue.*

Comment: Does this mentioned game above come in a non-finish version? The documentation looks fun, but when I try to navigate around I get to finish pages.

Comment: @AdAbsurdum: the game was played in a way that you supplied a bunch of numbers in text-file to the game (no language barrier). The only useful information is the English site.

Comment: ...the inspiration to this game comes from Strategem and some book `Limits-to-growth` (according to my instructor), only a triviality to know but they may contain something to look at.

Comment: this would be a good idea and should be extended

Answer (score 3):

Try this: if you win this, you are really good ;)

- The **Heritage Health Prize**, is a contest to predict the admission of patients. The company provides you historical data. This is a very interesting exercise where you can apply AI and statistics/econometrics http://www.heritagehealthprize.com/c/hhp
- if you are looking for different projects, why not join **Kaggle** (http://www.kaggle.com) ? Kaggle is a crowdsourcing website trying to match people/companies which have problems to solve with data scientists. There are often prizes.

The Heritage Health Prize has started a long time ago and the level of competition is quite high, so I would not expect to even have a chance to win the prize if I started now, but it can be interesting nevertheless especially that your research on the patients admissions will have real world impact if useful !

If you are serious about this and preferably living in London, drop me a message, I would like to do some research but I would like to be part of a group.

The Heritage Health Prize is not an investment game per se, but is kind of related to actuarial sciences and the skillset require overlaps with financial timeseries analysis.

Comment: Kaggle is a great site.

Comment: @jlowin: are you looking for someone to join your team ?